# Генерация документации на основе комментариев в C# коде

Tags: c#, документация

Мне нужно внутри моего C# проекта генерировать документацию на основе комментариев в исходниках. Пробовал Doxygen, но он генерирует много мусора в XML (например, сгенерировал XML для class1 и class2, а он кроме файлов class_class1.xml и class_class2.xml сгенерировал ещё кучу всяких xml, xslt, xsd), а желательно, чтобы всего было по-минимуму. Есть какие-нибудь похожие инструменты? Или может можно как-то упростить вывод Doxygen'а?

Comment: SandCastle пробовали? https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB

Comment: *Пробовал Doxygen, но он генерирует много мусора* — возможно, вы не до конца разобрались, «как его готовить»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я прошелся по документации, и, как я понял, для XML там всего одна опция - GENERATE_XML

Comment: я немного о другом говорил. видимо, не понял, что вы подразумевали под словом «мусор».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Дополнил

Comment: @acedened хм, ну сгенерил он "кучу всяких" ещё, а чем они вам мешают? Лишнее лучше чем когда не хватает, не? Ну на крайний случай сделайте билд который их будет удалять.

Comment: @acedened, в качестве «мусора» вы обозначили [необходимые файлы](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html#xml_out). но если они вам *действительно* не нужны, вы можете просто удалять их после генерации. для упрощения и ускорения процедуры можно скрипт какой-нибудь написать, который будет сначала запускать *doxygen*, а потом удалять файлы/каталоги, которые вы считаете ненужными.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, они мне действительно не нужны. Мне нужна только информация о классе и его членах. Значит буду удалять их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в качестве «мусора» вы обозначили [необходимые файлы](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#xml_out).

но если они вам **действительно** не нужны, вы можете просто удалять их после генерации.

для упрощения и ускорения процедуры можно скрипт какой-нибудь написать, который будет сначала запускать *doxygen*, а потом удалять файлы/каталоги, которые вы считаете ненужными:

```
doxygen doxygen.cfg
rm xml/...
```